# Не получается запустить cron на Open Serverе?

Tags: cron, openserver, crontab, планировщик-задач

Уважаемые эксперты!

Пытаюсь научиться пользоваться Планировщиком заданий (Кроном) в Open Server и запускать php скрипты по расписанию. Делаю как на картинке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А скрипт такой:

```
require_once ('phpQuery-onefile.php');
$url = 'https://www.englishforcing.ru/o-nas/karta-sajta/';
$file = file_get_contents($url);
    preg_match_all('|<li class="wsp-post">(.+)</li>|', $file, $matches);

foreach ($matches[0] as $key => $value) {
    if (is_string($value)) {
        var_dump(substr($value, 21));
        $cut = substr($value, 128);
        $output = 'https://yandex.ru/search/xml?user=&key=&query=' . urlencode($cut) . '&lr==ru&sortby=&filter=none&maxpassages=5&groupby=ocs-in-group%3D3';
        $result = file_get_contents($output);
        var_dump($result);
        $fp = fopen("xml.txt", "a+");
        fwrite($fp, $result);
        fclose($fp);
        $i = 0;
        $i++;
        if ($i >= 5) {break;}
    }
}
```

Скрипт не отрабатывает. Мне кажется, дело в том, что я должен указать что-то еще, кроме url скрипта.. Но многочисленные руководства написаны не очень внятно. Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему, если есть лишняя минутка..

Comment: а когда через браузер вы его пытаетесь открыть он срабатывает без ошибок? вы не проверяете на успех $fp = fopen("xml.txt", "a+"); есть ли права у веб-сервера на текущую директорию из которой исполняется скрипт?

Comment: Яков, здравствуйте! Если открывать без планировщика - все срабатывает и выдача записывается в xml.txt. Если включить запуск по расписанию, как я делаю, то в логах пишется следующее: 07 Oct 12:07:00 Start: C:\Users\Валентин\Desktop\OpenServer\domains\localhost\par.php
07 Oct 12:07:00 Start result: 0

Comment: скрипт выполняется из localhost, так что, да, права есть..

Comment: При запуске скрипта из планировщика запись в xml.txt не происходит..

Comment: а планировщик знает чем "выполнять" php-скрипт попробуйте указать *путь к интерпретатору*\php -f *путь*\par.php? как костыль можно поставить wget и дергать обычным планировщиком скрипт с локалхоста. опять же еще раз под каким пользователем у вас работает планировщик и под каким работает веб-сервер? они могут быть разными и соотв. права на папку где выполняется скрипт для них будут разными. для теста укажите путь к файлу на диске c:\all\xml.txt и дайте доступ туда всем на запись и чтение. чтобы проверить.

Comment: Попробовал добавить путь к интерпретатору в том синтаксисе, который вы прислали.. Реестр логов выдает то же самое.. и в xml.txt ничего не записывает.. Права доступа тоже открыл..

Comment: После этого так же не сработало..

Comment: так попробуй другой скрипт. может вообще планировщик не работает. или пользователь другой используется. попробуй открыть файл в директории с полным доступом всем. и записать туда просто 123. для теста. например сделай папку c:\temp, и в нее запиши файл test.txt, к примеру запустив cmd.exe /c echo 1234>c:\temp\test.txt, в разрешениях ntfs добавь группу Все и поставь полный доступ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Планировщик начал записывать спаршенную информацию в файл xml.txt после того, как добавил в пути wget и url скрипта с http://

Вот так это выглядит: `W:\modules\wget\bin\wget.exe -q --no-cache http://localhost/par.php`

[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]